# Отображение разных таблиц с разными sql запросами

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Есть tabbedPane в ней несколько вкладок с таблицами JTable. В первую вкладку с таблицей загружается полностью таблица из БД. Я хочу чтобы в остальные таблицы загружалась не полностью таблица, а с разными sql запросами. Как правильно написать запросы, чтобы при открытии каждой вкладки была видна  таблица со своей выборкой?

```
public class Success extends javax.swing.JFrame {      
    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String sql, sqlSO;
    String status;
    DefaultTableModel model, modelSO, modelSTZ,modelMaterials, modelProducts, modelWaste;
    Product product;
    Statement st;


        public Success()  {

        initComponents();        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        show_product();    
        }   


     public ArrayList<Product> productList() throws SQLException{
      ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         conn = getConnection(); 
         st= conn.createStatement();
         if (table_allProduct.isVisible()){
             sql = "select * from product";           
         }
        if (table_SO.isVisible()){
             sql = "select * from product where status = 'СО'";        
         }
         rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
         Product product;
         while(rs.next()){
             product = new Product(
                      rs.getInt("id"),
                      rs.getInt("kod"),
                      rs.getString("marking"),                      
                      rs.getString("name"),
                      rs.getString("unit"),
                      rs.getDouble("quantity"),
                      rs.getString("type"),
                      rs.getString("status"),
                      rs.getString("place"),
                      rs.getString("declaration"),
                      rs.getString("idata"));
             productList.add(product);             
         }         
      }  
       return productList;}


    public void show_product() throws SQLException{    
       ArrayList<Product> list = productList();       
       model =(DefaultTableModel) table_allProduct.getModel(); 
       modelSO = (DefaultTableModel) table_SO.getModel(); 
       modelSTZ = (DefaultTableModel) table_STZ.getModel(); 
       modelMaterials = (DefaultTableModel) table_material.getModel(); 
       modelProducts = (DefaultTableModel) table_production.getModel(); 
       modelWaste = (DefaultTableModel) table_waste.getModel(); 
       Object[] row = new Object[11];
       for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
          row[0]=list.get(i).getId();
          row[1]=list.get(i).getMarking();
          row[2]=list.get(i).getName();
          row[3]=list.get(i).getUnit();
          row[4]=list.get(i).getQuantity();
          row[5]=list.get(i).getType();
          row[6]=list.get(i).getStatus();
          row[7]=list.get(i).getPlace();
          row[8]=list.get(i).getDeclaration();
          row[9]=list.get(i).getKod();
          row[10]=list.get(i).getIdata(); 
           if(table_allProduct.isVisible()) {
              model.addRow(row);
           }if (table_SO.isVisible()) {
              modelSO.addRow(row);
           }if (table_STZ.isVisible()) {
              modelSTZ.addRow(row);
           }if (table_material.isVisible()) {
              modelMaterials.addRow(row);
           }if (table_production.isVisible()) {
              modelProducts.addRow(row);
           }if (table_waste.isVisible()) {
              modelWaste.addRow(row);
           } 
           }

       }
```

}

Comment: Советую вам перейти на hibernate или что-то подобное. На сотой таблице сотого поля вам надоест писать `rs.getInt()`

Comment: не совсе понятна архитектура приложения. show_product() вызывается на каком событии?

Comment: @Ramiz  добавила код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно информации из комментариев, на активизацию вкладки, код должен загружать данные в соответствующую таблицу. тогда попробуйте следующим образом:

1. определить какая таблица активна на событие изменения состояния tabbedPane, а не используя isVisible т.к. последнее не изменяется когда мы переключаемся на другую вкладку.
2. определить критерий поиска для активной таблицы
3. загрузить результат в модель активной таблицы

например так:

```
public class Success extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    enum Type {
        ALL,
        SO,
        STZ,
        MATERIAL,
        PRODUCT,
        WASTE;

        public static Type valueOf(int id) {
            return values()[id];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form success
     */
    public Success() {
        initComponents();

        // load products on tab change
        tabbedPane_allProduct.addChangeListener(changeEvent -> {
            showProductsForCurrentTab();
        });

        // load initially open tab
        showProductsForCurrentTab();
    }

    private void showProductsForCurrentTab() {
        try {
            showProduct(Type.valueOf(tabbedPane_allProduct.getSelectedIndex()));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            txt_result.setText("Товары не загружены" + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Product> productList(String criteria) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("select * from product ");

        if (criteria != null)
            sql.append(" where ").append(criteria);
        // TODO consider predictable ordering of your query
        // sql.append(" order by id");

        ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Connection conn = getConnection();
             Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql.toString())) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Product product = new Product(
                        rs.getInt("id"),
                        rs.getInt("kod"),
                        rs.getString("marking"),
                        rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getString("unit"),
                        rs.getDouble("quantity"),
                        rs.getString("type"),
                        rs.getString("status"),
                        rs.getString("place"),
                        rs.getString("declaration"),
                        rs.getString("idata"));
                productList.add(product);
                txt_result.setText("Товары загружены");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            txt_result.setText("Товары не загружены" + ex);
        }

        return productList;
    }

    private void showProduct(Type type) throws SQLException {
        // detect visible table, get its model and define suitable criteria
        DefaultTableModel model;
        String criteria;
        switch (type) {
            case ALL:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_allProduct.getModel();
                criteria = null;
                break;
            case SO:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_SO.getModel();
                criteria = "status = 'CO'";
                break;
            case STZ:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_STZ.getModel();
                criteria = "status = 'СТЗ'";
                break;
            case MATERIAL:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_material.getModel();
                criteria = null; // TODO define criteria
                break;
            case PRODUCT:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_production.getModel();
                criteria = null; // TODO define criteria
                break;
            case WASTE:
                model = (DefaultTableModel) table_waste.getModel();
                criteria = null; // TODO define criteria
                break;
            default:
                // abort flow: probably programming error
                // TODO replace RuntimeException by proper one
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type " + type);
        }
        // загрузка данных
        ArrayList<Product> list = productList(criteria);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object[] row = new Object[11];
            row[0] = list.get(i).getId();
            row[1] = list.get(i).getMarking();
            row[2] = list.get(i).getName();
            row[3] = list.get(i).getUnit();
            row[4] = list.get(i).getQuantity();
            row[5] = list.get(i).getType();
            row[6] = list.get(i).getStatus();
            row[7] = list.get(i).getPlace();
            row[8] = list.get(i).getDeclaration();
            row[9] = list.get(i).getKod();
            row[10] = list.get(i).getIdata();

            model.addRow(row);
        }
    }
```

**внимание:** код приведен для иллюстрации идеи и не может быть вставлен в продукитвное приложение "как есть"!

Comment: Не загружается в остальные вкладки таблица только в первую и ошибки нет. Вот так выглядит http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280718/OQuQD5Id   При открытии загружаются все товары

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч тогда покажите код в котором создается Success, а лучше ссылку на весь минимальный запускаемый пример

Comment: тут минимально работающий пример https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9VCq/oeZjhjm1M. Я пользуюсь NetBeans

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч спасибо. т.е. Success создается один раз при запуске приложение, следовательно show_product() вызывается тоже только один раз, т.е. все продукты должны грузиться одним запросом и потом распределяться по вкладкам. Если так, то мой ответ, как собственно и ваша формулировка вопроса не верны. Если нет, то можно переделать приложение таким образом чтобы продукты грузились на событие активации соответствующей таблицы.

Comment: Идея была грузить на событие активации соответствующей таблицы. Если в главной таблице происходит изменение (добавление, удаление, изменение) то и остальные должны тоже изменится.

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч обновил ответ, запустить не удалось, потому что нужна база, но, думаю, можно и так попробовать.

Comment: Теперь так получилось https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LE63/JqMt8qRDn. При открытии не грузится первая таблица, только после переключения вкладок. Остальные так и не загрузились. Может дело в том, что таблицы располагаются на jScrollPane http://skrinshoter.ru/s/300718/stmu7Jqy.

Comment: обновил ответ: т.к. isVisible у таблиц в данном коде всегда true, то грузилась только таблица со всеми продуктами, теперь мы будем грузить на переключение вкладок опираясь на индекс активной вкладки.

Comment: Спасибо большое